# Adjective complement with no "to be"

Tags: adjectives, object-complements

> Teacher called these students difficult to control.

In this sentence, there is no "to be" between difficult and students, which somehow so strangely led me to thinking that using adjective complement "to control" after adjective "difficult" is wrong. Is it OK to use adjective complement when there is no "to be"?

Another example.

> Students were called difficult to control.

So, are those sentences grammatically correct? Thank you so much in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If you consider "difficult to control" as a *label* describing the students, then it is OK.

> *The/My* teacher called these students "difficult to control".

Quotes added to define the phrase, but not required.

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer. But there is one thing that I do not quiet get... what do you mean by label?

Comment: See [***label***](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/american/label) - "3. a descriptive word or phrase applied to a person, group, theory, etc. as a convenient generalized classification"

Comment: Thank you! Also, is it OK to use this adjective complement with other adjectives even if there is no "to be"? For example: He made the program difficult to understand.

Answer (score 0):

You correctly identify the adjectivals as *complements*. Many verbs besides *BE* take obligatory or optional complements of this sort, both adjectival and nominal.

> I consider him *honest*.
>   The company named her *president*.
>   John painted the door *red*.
>   I declare this meeting *open*.
>   Let's make this *an option*.

Other verbs—often called *linking* verbs—take complements which describe the subject.

> I feel *sick*.
>   He seems *an honest man*.

And it is often possible to add a 'secondary' subject complement to ordinary intransitive verbs.

> The wolf's teeth shone *white* in the moonlight.
>   Night settled *dark and silent* over the forest.